# app not running in release mode after connection with firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, authentication, firebase-authentication

I have connected my app to firebase and then I did steps for phone authentication but now when I run my app in release mode it doesn't run and shows error below-:

```
Running "flutter pub get" in tax...                             0.7s
Launching lib\main.dart on Redmi Note 7 Pro in release mode...
Note: C:\Src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_core-0.7.0\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebase\core\FlutterFirebaseCorePlugin.
java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\geolocator-5.3.2+2\android\src\main\java\com\baseflow\geolocator\tasks\LocationUpdatesUsingLocationMa
nagerTask.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform libs.jar to match attributes {artifactType=processed-jar, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: C:\Users\PALAK\AndroidStudioProjects\tax\build\app\intermediates\flutter\debug\libs.jar.
         > Transform's input file does not exist: C:\Users\PALAK\AndroidStudioProjects\tax\build\app\intermediates\flutter\debug\libs.jar. (See https://i
ssuetracker.google.com/issues/158753935)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 8s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                      69.7s
Exception: Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

i have no idea why this is happening can anyone guide me please?

Comment: Can you show me build gradle in project level?

Comment: buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

Comment: Go to Project/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties , then show me what is inside this file

Comment: #Wed Feb 17 10:23:16 IST 2021
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-bin.zip

Answer (score 0):

> Replace "bin" with "all" in
> Project/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties I mean change
> 6.5-bin.zip to 6.5-all.zip

Then do `flutter clean` and try.

Comment: @palak What is the dependencies in app/build.gradle ?

Comment: implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.5.0')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'

Comment: @palak I think you must edit your question and add all important files like: pubspec.yaml, app/gradle and root/gradle

Answer (score 0):

did you provide the internet permission in manifest like this ?

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: downgrade grade to 4.0.1 &
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip

Comment: which grade 4.0.1 ?

Comment: this one    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'